# Python class order

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I was just trying some things with the python classes and wondered about the order of them. Does python offer a solution to put the class C before class A and B and still inherit things from them?

```
class A:
    def input_name(self):
        user_input_name = input("Name please\n")
        A.user_input_name = user_input_name

class B:
    def input_age(self):
        user_input_age = input("Age please\n")
        B.user_input_age = user_input_age

class C(A,B):
    def output(self):
        print(C.user_input_name)
        print(C.user_input_age)
        print("Hi {0}!\n".format(self.user_input_name))


eka = A()
eka.input_name()

toka = B()
toka.input_age()

kolmas = C()
kolmas.output()
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly by *put the class C before class A and B*?

Comment: try it out and see?

Comment: @Kasramvd I mean would it be possible to somehow initialize class A and B if class C was the first class in order. Class C would still be inheriting both class A and B.

Comment: You can't inherit from something that's undefined at the time you're trying to inherit it…

Comment: Everything in python is about run time (except some internal compiled time optimizations), i.e. you cannot do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't. `class` is an executable statement that creates the class object at runtime and bind it to the class name in the current scope. Until this statement is executed, the class object doesn't exist *and* the name is not defined either, so you cannot reference it.